# Microsoft Access Disable User Input for Automation

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a known way, direct or workaround, by which I can disable ms access 2003 asking for user input. I have a method in which I can call a VBA procedure and I run this with a scheduled task when everyone is out of the database at around 6:30 AM. Yet I found an error in one of my queries where a space wasn't present and access was asking for that value of that column. I also found an error in some code where it results in launching the debugger and never continues (resulting in a time-out).

These are not classified as errors because I have a method in which the program sends an email on error. I need a way to disable events in which the application waits for user input, like a erroneous query or the activation of the debugger etc...

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run with scissors. It would be better to test your changes rather than deploying them blind upon your users. However, that said...

You can disable activation of break points by un-checking "Use Access Special Keys" in the Tools->Startup options.

You can disable error checking in the Tools->Options form (Error Checking tab).

And of course you can pass parameters to MS-Access queries (rather than require user input) - see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95277).

Comment: Yeah I understand. We are actually just updating linked tables that come from another datasource. That would be horrible if I just threw changes to forms and data at the users like that. lol.

But thanks man. This is a very helpful response. I was hoping there would be options to disable breaking.

Answer (score -1):

try the "on error resume next" ...

Comment: I know that.. I have a function that I want to handle errors that emails us when an error occurs. So Im not interested in skipping the errors, just catch all errors.