# Escape input data in SQL queries when using ODBC + Access

Tags: php, windows, ms-access, odbc

I've tried `odbc_prepare()` + `odbc_execute()` to update a record in an Access file but I always get an `SQL state 07001` error message about incorrect column count (actually, the message is in Spanglish and doesn't make much sense):

```
<?php
$items = array();
$items[100] = 'Foo';
$items[200] = 'Bar';
$sql = 'UPDATE street
    SET name=?
    WHERE street_id=?';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conection, $sql);
if( $stmt===FALSE ){
    die(odbc_errormsg());
}
foreach($items as $cod => $name){
    if( !odbc_execute($stmt, array($name, $cod)) ){
        die(odbc_errormsg());
    }
}
```

User comments at [odbc_execute manual page](http://php.net/odbc_execute) suggest that Microsoft Access ODBC drivers do not support parameterized queries. However, I haven't found an odbc_* function to escape data.

So... How can I escape input data?

Comment: No offence, but Access?????? Thow it away and use a proper database.

Comment: @Spudley, what data format would you recommend to upload data to an Oracle-driven web site using a browser?

Comment: Hi There, can you clarify that, are you loading data to an Access database so that you can then load that to an Oracle database?

Comment: @MikeAinOz: I'm fixing an existing Access file (provided by the customer) to be loaded later into Oracle. The importer is designed to discard wrong data and I don't want to rewrite it and make it guess: I prefer to guess myself :) Whatever, I think it's a good question by itself, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying out random stuff. It seems that `odbc_prepare()` detects parameters if you use one of these syntaxes (or you even mix them):

- `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (:param)`
- `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ([param])`

However, `odbc_execute()` will complain about missing parameters no matter what you feed it with (numeric array, associative array...). And it'll know the exact number of parameters that cannot be found. That makes the whole mechanism completely pointless.

Sad to say, my best solution so far is this:

```
/**
 * Escape a string to be inserted into Access via ODBC
 */
function odbc_escape_string_access($value){
    $replacements= array(
        "'" => "''",
    );
    return strtr($value, $replacements);
}
```

It's horrible but I couldn't find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in MS Access, you identify the parameters by placing them in brackets

```
$sql = 'UPDATE street
        SET name=[myname]
        WHERE street_id=[mystreet]';
```

How that will mesh with php, I don't know.

Comment: How do you escape brackets? `UPDATE street
        SET name=[myname [1]]
        WHERE street_id=[123]`

Comment: Try $sql = `UPDATE street SET name=['.myname[1].'] WHERE street_id=' etc... pardon my rusty PHP concat

Comment: Don't worry about PHP (I'm assuming that if there was a function to escape someone would have pointed out so far). What would be the plain SQL query?

Comment: @Mike - Wouldn't putting single quotes in allow for SQL injection?

Comment: Part of the problem with MS Access is that passing parameters through code wasn't documented very well. So everyone who has written up instructions has only written up instructions for the style where MS Access asks the user for input on the fly, rather than passing them in through code. For many years I though the only way to do it was to build the SQL on the fly and submit that (of course leaving your self open to enjection), but then I found this trick - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95277/how-do-you-create-a-parameterized-query-in-ms-access-2003-and-use-other-queries-f/96134#96134

Comment: @CodeSlave I agree with you that a VBA solution would be better, however this is currently PHP and any SQL injection issues will have to be handled in PHP

Comment: Yah, VBA was just intended an example of how it's handled in the VBA side for inspiration. The brackets just indicate where the parameters are. You probably have to dereference the array and pass the values in as you did in the for loop.