# Correct way to escape input data before passing to ODBC

Tags: php, odbc, escaping, user-input, mysql-real-escape-string

I am very used to using MySQL and mysql_real_escape_string(), but I have been given a new PHP project that uses ODBC.

What is the correct way to escape user input in a SQL string?

Is addslashes() sufficient?

I would like to get this right now rather than later!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of string escaping the PHP ODBC driver uses prepared statements. Use [odbc_prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) to prepare an SQL statement and odbc_execute to pass in the parameters and execute the statements. (This is similar to what you can do with PDO).

Comment: Looks exactly like what I want.  However, I'm completely new to prepared statements too.  By using prepared statements, can I pass in special characters without worrying about escaping?  e.g. to pass **O'Brien** in as a parameter, I just pass it in using odbc_exec into a prepared statement?

Comment: Yes, that's what prepared statements are for. They prevent SQL Injections as the DBMS handles the parameters for you.

Comment: Prepared statements are the most sensible approach. In practice, though, not all ODBC drivers support them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario What would be the alternative to drivers which do not support those?

Comment: @PacMani - I've [had that problem myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996275/escape-input-data-in-sql-queries-when-using-odbc-access) and didn't find a satisfactory answer. As far as I know your only chance is reading technical docs to find out the DBMS mechanism and writing your own escape function.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Okay, I just helped myself by simply replacing ' with '' in my case... not very secure, but the code is only used internally anyways...

Comment: Prepared statements are great until you run into a bug such as: a parameter marker in a LIKE clause will cause a "String data, right truncation" if the bound value is too long (which is bogus; LIKE isn't supposed to generate that kind of error) (with PHP ODBC and SQL Server native driver on Windows, that is)