# Update Filemaker Pro over ODBC with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, filemaker

I'm Updating with mysql over ODBC Filemaker Table.
When a field contains o'reilly or example'two I get this error message:

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:80):
There is an error in the syntax of the query., SQL state 42000 in SQLExecDirect  in C:\fm_1.php on line 49

and using addslashes() does not work.

thank you!

this is my code:

```
<?php
$conn = odbc_connect("DSN=Server;Database=TEST;UID=odbc;PWD=1234", "odbc", "1234");
if ($conn)
    echo "\nConnection established.";
else
    die("\nConnection could not be established.");

$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT ID_MH, MH_Name FROM myTable WHERE MH_Name LIKE '%EXAMPLE'");
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ID_MH = $row["ID_MH"];
    $MH_Name = $row["MH_Name"]; 

    // do something

    $MH_Name = addslashes($MH_Name);
    $update = "UPDATE myTable SET MH_Name='$MH_Name' WHERE ID_MH=" . $ID_MH;    
    $data_update = odbc_exec($conn, $update);

} 
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Is MySQL actually relevant here? The posted code only seems to deal with the FMP database via ODBC.

Comment: The correct solution to this problem is to use `odbc_prepare()/odbc_execute()` instead of `odbc_exec()` with variables in your SQL statement. But you should verify if FMP supports prepared statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713837/correct-way-to-escape-input-data-before-passing-to-odbc

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape instead of using addslashes:

"UPDATE myTable SET MH_Name=\"$MH_Name\" WHERE ID_MH=" . $ID_MH;

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
$query = 'UPDATE myTable SET MH_Name=? WHERE ID_MH=?';
$stmt = odbc_prepare ($conn, $query);
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($MH_Name, $ID_MH));
```

source:https://www.skeletonkey.com/FileMaker_11_ODBC_Drivers/

thanks!