# MS Access 2010 VBA runtime error 3075 (searching with apostrophes)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The answer is probably really simple - I just can't come up with the right search term, I suspect.

I have a form that opens another form, displaying any employee record that matches the search as entered  You can search by surname, given name, or employee ID (using separate buttons); it gives you a little message box if your search turns up nothing.

The code works fine, except for the usual problem with handling apostrophes in names ("O'Neill," "O'Brien," etc.)  I found a really simple apostrophe handling function, but when I try to use the function in the search query it still throws up a 3075 runtime error, and I'm not sure why.  It only throws up the runtime error with apostrophe-containing searches, so I feel like the function maybe isn't doing what I think it is.

I am happy to entertain solutions that involve "using this function but adding more quotation marks (or whatever)" as well as whole new ideas.  I'd prefer to use something *like* this function, though, because it's so small and thus it'll be much faster and cleaner to replace the search-by-name code each place that it appears.

This is the code that works fine:

```
Private Sub btnSearchSurname_Click()

Dim frm As Form
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = "[List_Employees.Surname] like '" & Me.EmpSurname & "*'"
strSearch = strSearch & " AND [CurrentEmployee] = " & True
DoCmd.OpenForm "Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs", , , strSearch, , acHidden
Set frm = Forms("Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs")
If frm.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    frm.Visible = True
    Else
    MsgBox ("Employee not found.  Try the 'all' button to see if they're inactive.  If that doesn't work, please check for typos and try again.")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs"
    Call OpenPayrollCloseRest
End If

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Find_An_Employee"
```

I'm trying to use [this simple public function to handle apostrophes](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/636687-apostrophes-names):

```
Public Function adhHandleQuotes(ByVal varValue As Variant, Optional Delimiter As String = "'") As Variant
    ' Replace all instances of a string delimiter with TWO instances,
    ' thereby handling the darned quote issue once and for all. Also,
    ' surround the string with the delimiter, as well.

    ' Returns Null if the String was Null, otherwise
    ' returns the String with all instances of strDelimiter
    ' replaced with two of each.

    adhHandleQuotes = strDelimiter & Replace(varValue, strDelimiter, strDelimiter & strDelimiter) & strDelimiter
End Function
```

I modified the search code to use the function by inserting three lines lines in place of the first "strSearch = " line:

```
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strTerm As String

strTerm = adhHandleQuotes(Me.EmpSurname)
strSearch = "[List_Employees.Surname] like '" & strTerm & "*'"
strSearch = strSearch & " AND [CurrentEmployee] = " & True
DoCmd.OpenForm "Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs", , , strSearch, , acHidden
```

And this is the runtime error dialogue box:

[image: Runtime Error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[List_Employees.Surname] like 'o'cal*' AND [CurrentEmployee]=True']

Comment: Your function `adhHandleQuotes` is using `strDelimiter` in the code, but the optional parameter's name is `Delimiter`. Have you checked what `adhHandleQuotes(Me.EmpSurname)` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you even need a function? Just simply incorporate a Double Quotes, my hack is to use Chr(34).

```
Private Sub btnSearchSurname_Click()

    Dim frm As Form
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "[List_Employees.Surname] Like " & Chr(34) & Me.EmpSurname & "*" & Chr(34)
    strSearch = strSearch & " AND [CurrentEmployee] = True"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs", , , strSearch, , acHidden

    Set frm = Forms("Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs")
    If frm.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        frm.Visible = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("Employee not found.  Try the 'all' button to see if they're inactive.  If that doesn't work, please check for typos and try again.")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Employee_Entry_Extended_Certs"
        Call OpenPayrollCloseRest
    End If

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Find_An_Employee"
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was trying to do the danged Chr(34) for about an hour yesterday; I think I must have just misplaced an apostrophe in there because copy/paste of your line works perfectly.  My clerks will be so pleased not to have to scroll through the entire list of employees whose names start with O now.  :)

Comment: Glad to be of help ! Good luck @Sarah :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:
[Access VBA, unescaped single quotes, Replace(), and null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893861/access-vba-unescaped-single-quotes-replace-and-null)

Rather than doubling your apostrophe, it surrounds it with double quotes.