# How to prompt user input parameters for SQL Queries in Access 2010

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT Transactions.TransactionNumber
FROM Transactions
WHERE (((Transactions.Date)>=#11/23/12#)) AND (((Transactions.Date)<=#11/23/12#));
```

The above code returns all the transaction that happened between the specified dates. But I want those dates to be defined by the user every time the query is executed.

I tried using the [] operators to have the user define the criteria in the WHERE, something like this:

```
WHERE (((Transactions.Date)>=[Input a Date])) AND (((Transactions.Date)<=[Input a Date]));
```

But microsoft Access throws a Syntax error message. The same happens when I include the # (date operators) like this

```
WHERE (((Transactions.Date)>=#[Input a Date]#)) AND (((Transactions.Date)<=#[Input a Date]#));
```

Is there anopther way to manage dates that I'm not aware of or is asking a user for dates in a query out of the question

Answer (score 1):

Please,take a look at this link for [user input criteria in queries](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-HA010096314.aspx#_Toc267474485)

you can use query builder to do this part for you and then work fully on the SQL editor.

In that case you let system help you do the format it accepts user inputs.

Comment: I reckon that it would be best to jump straight to form input, that way, the user can select the dates from a calendar control and the dates can be reused. It is frustrating to have to type the same dates several times, which is often the case http://stackoverflow.com/a/97350/2548

Comment: So yeah in the above link it shows how to use a calendar control :-)

Comment: Yes, I saw, and if I was a new user I would give up and go home with that level of complication :) The late D.W. Fenton's example looks so much easier.

Comment: Yeah all helpful resources. all think in different way, good to have better more choices. +1 for that. Btw Remou, D.W.Fenton passed away? :o

Comment: Yes, just over a year ago http://www.davis-andersonfuneralhome.com/obits/obituaries.php/obitID/435707/obit/David-W-Fenton

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parentheses is the cause of the syntax error. Try below.

WHERE (((Date)>=[Input a Date1])) AND (((Date)<=[Input a Date2]));

Answer (score 0):

Found thi post googling for a similar problem: query returnig wrong values when using between [param1] and [param2] whereas params are supposed to be date type. Access does't know nor recognize input parameters ad date but treat them as text. Me too tried coding sql staement to force recognition (and also convertion since we use dd/mm/yyyy format) with no success.
I SOLVED the problem setting parameters date type in the query design view, and non need of format function or including # symbols in the sql statement