# SQL/ACCESS Data Conversion Error 3421

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

A listbox is populated with values from a separate table. The value of this listbox is being inserted into the transactions table as a new record. Access throwing an error "Data Type Conversion Error 3421" When I attempt to assign the value of the listbox to my sql paramater. The Listbox is txtMealType, it is being inserted as MealID, which is a short text field.

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim vblMealType As String
txtMealType.SetFocus
vblMealType = txtMealType.Value
If (txtMealType & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Long, prmMealID Long, prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate DateTime;" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate]) ")
qdf!prmCustomerID = txtCustomerID.Value


qdf!prmTransactionAmount = txtCharge.Value
txtCharge.SetFocus
qdf!prmTransactionDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
qdf!prmMealID = vblMealType
qdf.Execute
 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the prmMealId as a long in the query definition.

Is vblMealType a long or a short text field as you stated.  Use CLNG() to convert the string to a long and fix the data type conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the field types in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19960787/2144390) so I guessed based on the (absence of) quoting in your original SQL string. If [MealID] is `Short Text` in the table then in the PARAMETERS statement above change

```
prmMealID Long,
```

to

```
prmMealID Text(255),
```