# Access INSERT query not working on SQL Server linked table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The code below is supposed to insert a record into the transactions table. The code runs with no errors, however when looking at the transactions table no new row has been inserted.

```vbs
If txtMealID.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please Select a Meal Type", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
Dim vblMealType As String
vblMealType = txtMealID.Value
MsgBox " " & vblMealType & " ", vbCritical + vbApplicationModal
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Long, prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate DateTime;" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate]) ")


qdf!prmCustomerID = txtCustomerID.Value
qdf!prmMealID = vblMealType
txtCharge.SetFocus
qdf!prmTransactionAmount = txtCharge.Value

qdf!prmTransactionDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

It appears that the problem is with the Set qdf Line. My MsgBox " " & vblMealType & " will not trigger when the Set qdf line is present.

Comment: When you say "looking at the transactions table" do you mean looking at the linked [dbo_Transactions] table in Datasheet View from within Access itself? If so, then have you tried closing and re-opening the table in Access to see if the new record shows up then?

Comment: You appear to be initializing `vblMealType` with no value, then passing it as a parameter to your query.  MealID may require a non-zero-length-string value.  If you execute your query using `qdf.Execute dbFailOnError`, you'll get an error if there is something wrong with it or its parameters.

Comment: Make sure your VBA options shows "Break on all errors" as you trouble shoot this.

Comment: Didn't you just ask about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960787/access-sql-too-few-parameters?

Comment: I fixed the vblMealType problem, and added the FailonError. The code still does nothing, now the msgbox does not show and the code simply does nothing.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20036438/edit) your question to show your updated code.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a sample form and it worked fine for me. You can download the sample database [here](http://wikisend.com/download/254332/dboTransactionsTest.zip) if you want to try it for yourself. You will need to use the [Linked Table Manager](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/view-refresh-or-change-the-file-name-and-path-for-linked-tables-mdb-HP005187623.aspx) in Access to update the [dbo_Transactions] linked table to use your ODBC DSN.

Answer (score -1):

You should test this workaround, avoiding using DAO query object, but rather using SQL execution provided by DAO::Database.

```
Private Sub sofInsert20036438_Click()

  If txtMealID.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Meal Type", _
      vbOKOnly + vbInformation
  Else

    Dim strSQL As String, vblMealType As String
    Dim dbs

    vblMealType = txtMealID.Value
    MsgBox " " & vblMealType & " ", vbCritical + vbApplicationModal
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    'Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
    '  "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Long, prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate DateTime;" & _
    '  "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
    '  "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate]) ")

    'qdf!prmCustomerID = txtCustomerID.Value
    'qdf!prmMealID = vblMealType
    'txtCharge.SetFocus
    'qdf!prmTransactionAmount = txtCharge.Value

    'qdf!prmTransactionDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    'qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " _
      & "VALUES (" & txtCustomerID.Value _
      & ", '" & vblMealType & "'" _
      & ", " & txtCharge.Value _
      & ", #" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#);"

    dbs.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges

    If (dbs.RecordsAffected > 0) Then
      strSQL = "Customer Charge Succesfull."
    Else
      strSQL = "Error inserting."
    End If
    '
    MsgBox strSQL, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

'   Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```

Here the syntax of SQL string is supposed to use these fields definitions:

```
CustomerID: INT,
MealID: VARCHAR(255),
TransactionAmount: FLOAT,
TransactionDate: DATETIME.
```

Comment: @downvoter? I would like to understand you, and if you tested this code?

Comment: I downvoted your answer. **(1)** Telling someone to *not* use parameterized queries and "glue together" SQL statments is bad advice. **(2)** For database operations *within the Access application itself* DAO (not ADO) is still the preferred mechanism. I have tested the QueryDef approach against a SQL Server linked table and it *does* work, so there is something else wrong with the OP's code that we don't understand yet.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, OK, my reply is some workaround. His error is probably in date Format() without #...#...

Comment: Actually, no, query parameter values should contain no delimiters whatsoever. Adding hash marks to a Date parameter value would guarantee that the code would fail with a "Data type conversion error".

Comment: @Gord Thompson, You are right. It passes years since I converted UPDATING QueryDefs to SQL execute... I've forgotten parameters ;-(.