# SQL / Access Object Requires Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am intending to use the code below to insert a record into the database. However, it is throwing an object required error. I have checked and all the variables contain data.

```
Dim vblMealType As String
Dim vblMealQual As String


If txtMealID.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please Select a Meal Type", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else



 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation

Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

 ERROR ON THE VALUES LINE
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Text(255), prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate Text(255);" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate])")


qdf!prmCustomerID = txtCustomerID.Value
qdf!prmMealID = txtMealID.Value
qdf!prmTransactionAmount = txtCharge.Value
qdf!prmTransactionDate = Date
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenForm "Charge Form"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Comment: Was that a complete self-contained code example?  The reason I ask is because you have `If` and `Else` but no `End If`.  Does your code compile?

Comment: @HansUp If you check their [recent questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1698144/user1698144?tab=questions&sort=newest) you'll see that the last three are all related. They're flailing about trying to implement the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19961460/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, I see your point.  I think OP should include `Option Explicit`, then run Debug->Compile and clean up anything the compiler complains about.  *Then* see what problem remains and post a question about that problem.

Comment: @user1698144 You have `txtMealID.ItemsSelected.Count` and later `txtMealID.Value`.  So what is `txtMealID`: text; combo; or list box?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid that *"object required"* complaint, first declare and initialize `dbs` before you attempt to use it with `CreateQueryDef`.

```vb
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Text(255), prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate Text(255);" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate])")
```

Comment: Invalid Use of Property ("Set QDF")