# dynamically generating an SQL statement based on user form input

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to compile and build a dynamic SQL statement based on user input.

The way I see it is a bunch of if statements checking that each and everyone of the fields contain any data by using the .length > 0 method.

I don't see this as being the most productive way to accomplish this. Is there another method to this madness?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {

var sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_imts WHERE"

var date1 = document.getElementById('date1').value
var action = document.getElementById('action').value
var date2 = document.getElementById('date2').value
var reqtype = document.getElementById('reqtype').value
var status = document.getElementById('status').value
var assignto = document.getElementById('assignto').value


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>Date Received</td>
        <td>Action Required</td>
        <td>Due Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="date1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="action"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="date2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Request Type</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Assigned to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="reqtype"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="status"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="assignto"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="test it" onclick="test()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some evident security reasons, **NEVER WRITE ANY SQL QUERY IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT**. Anyone can modify javascript since it is executed client-side. Someone could modify your query to get... users list and their password for example.

Comment: For this purpose it will be a simple HTA application. The employees here are limited to what they know. Let's assume it is safe.

Comment: Do you use php in this application ?

Comment: I don't know what HTA means, but if you have *any* reason to care about the integrity of your system, this is not the way to do things.

Comment: HTA is an HTML application. It uses ADODB and MS Access. Simple GUI for tracking work ran clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use query parameters or else you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Never trust the client. Any disgruntled employee could cause serious damage to your data.

See: [How do you create a parameterized query in MS Access 2003 and use other queries/forms to fill the parameters and obtain a resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95277/how-do-you-create-a-parameterized-query-in-ms-access-2003-and-use-other-queries)