# "Build" a prepared SQL statement based on user-inputs with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

This question is a bit hard to phrase, but basically I have a form.  It's an account information form where a person can change the information associated with their account.  The catch is that the entire form gets submitted with each input being optional *(Leave input empty for no-change)* . So for example with this form you can change your city, address, and phone.  However a person can choose to only fill out city, press submit and just that info gets updated, all other info remains the same.

This might make more sense with the code in hand, here is the PHP I am using to accomplish this task; There are 4 lines with comments that contain code, these were left in since they were an attempt at answering my own question; they may help explain what I'm trying to achieve:

## PHP

```
// SQL HELPER
function prepared_Query($con, $sql, $params, $types = ""){
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt   = $con -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt -> execute();
    return $stmt;
}

// TRIM ALL POST VARS
function trim_Val(&$val){
    $val = trim($val);
}
array_filter($_POST, 'trim_Val');

// SANITIZE ALL INPUTS 
$filter = ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW];
$inputs = ['prov', 'city', 'addr', 'code', 'phone', 'phone_alt'];
$keys       = array_fill_keys($inputs, $filter);
$values    = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $keys);
unset($filter, $inputs, $keys); // cleanup

$sqlA   = [];
foreach($values as $key=>$val){
    if($val){
        $$key   = $val;
        //$sqlA[]   = "meta_".$key." = ?";
    }
}

//$sqlA = implode(", ", $sqlA);
//$sql  = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET ".$sqlA." WHERE meta_user = ?;";
//$stmt = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$$key, $uid]);

if(!empty($prov)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_prov = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$prov, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated Province";
}
if(!empty($city)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_city = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$city, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated City";
}
if(!empty($addr)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_addr = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$addr, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated Address";
}
if(!empty($code)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_code = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$code, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated Postal Code";
}
if(!empty($phone)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_phone = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$phone, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated Phone";
}
if(!empty($phone_alt)){
    $sql    = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_phone_alt = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
    $stmt   = prepared_Query($con, $sql, [$phone_alt, $uid]);
    $stmt   -> close();
    echo "Updated Alt. Phone";
}
$con -> close();
```

As you can probably tell I repeat that last function over and over again, and it seems silly to run that `$stmt` repeatedly when it could be accomplished with a single execute. From what I've learnt in my time with PHP and programming fundamentals, this is very WET code, where T is no longer twice but 6x too much.  In an attempt to solve this issue I created an array, then `foreach` input that was set; add the column name to that array.  Once finished `implode` the array using a comma separator.  Finally create the SQL statement using that imploded array.

This outputs a dynamically built SQL statement based on whatever inputs are set.  So if City and Address contain data the statement would look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET meta_city = ?, meta_addr = ? WHERE meta_user = ?;";
```

Now I have this working up to this point, depending on what inputs I've filled out the final output of the SQL statement is exactly what I want it to be.

## The problem...

...I have is when it comes to binding that statement to variable-Variables.  I don't know if its even possible to get *ALL* of the set var-vars into the parameters of this `prepared_Query()` function, when I have no idea which ones are set.

Possibly my logic is flawed, but I was so close to getting this to work I have to ask if there is a way I can accomplish this, or if it even makes sense doing it this way.  It makes sense to me, but I've gone down some pretty nasty blackholes with PHP before.  I'm sure there is someone out there with a bit more common sense than I.. when it comes to doing something like this.

So my question is, how can I bind variable Variables to a prepared SQL statement when each one is optional.  Is there any way to not have to write a separate statement for each input?  Or a shorter/faster way to do this?

These SO question are similar but do not answer the question I have:

[dynamically generating an SQL statement based on user form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986738/dynamically-generating-an-sql-statement-based-on-user-form-input)

[Dynamic SQL SELECT Statement with PHP based on user options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761462/dynamic-sql-select-statement-with-php-based-on-user-options)

There seems to be a few other questions out there phrased like this, but I could not find a clear example of someone trying to solve this same sort of problem.  This is what makes me think my logic is somehow flawed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

*Note: I think I've pasted everything relevant to the question, let me know if something is not clear.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both other answers are *almost* good.

The answer from @sh4dowb is good for constructing SELECT queries where could be different conditions that are hard to automatize. But for the UPDATE query it's no use to pick every clause by hand, a loop would be a much cleaner solution.

The approach demonstrated by @ooa is better but they forgot to create the actual update clauses. Besides, it is using these *despicable* variable variables.

But the right solution is almost there. We will use my example for PDO that accomplishes the same thing, [How to create a prepared statement for UPDATE query](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_update):

```
// the list of allowed field names
$allowed = ['prov', 'city', 'addr', 'code', 'phone', 'phone_alt'];

// initialize an array with values:
$params = [];

// initialize a string with `fieldname` = ? pairs
$setStr = "";

// loop over source data array
foreach ($allowed as $key)
{
    if (!empty($_POST[$key]) && $key != "id")
    {
        $setStr .= "`$key` = ?,";
        $params[] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
$setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");

$params[] = $_POST['id'];
prepared_query("UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET $setStr WHERE main_user = ?", [$params]);
```

And for goodness sake, forget about variable variables. There is **absolutely no use case** for them, yet they can do **a considerable harm**. `$_POST` array is an excellent source for your data, nothing else is needed.

Comment: >  they forgot to create the actual update clauses -- I haven't "forgotten" it, they already generate the correct SQL themselves with a single UPDATE statement. I merely advised on how to get that to work.

Comment: @ooa if user sends "city" parameter empty, it wouldn't work

Comment: btw you're missing a [ on first line but I can't send the edit because it's only one character

Comment: SMH... I knew I was close, I just need a bit of that Common Sense ;)  Thank you all for the answers.  I will work through this and after I get it working I'll come back and mark the correct answer.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do it like this;

```
$city = $_POST['city'];
$addr = $_POST['addr'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$condition = $_POST['condition'];

$bindParams = [];
$query = "UPDATE _MAIN_meta SET ";

if(!empty($city)){
    $query .= "meta_city = ?, ";
    $bindParams[] = $city;
}
if(!empty($addr)){
    $query .= "meta_addr = ?, ";
    $bindParams[] = $addr;
}
if(!empty($phone)){
    $query .= "meta_phone = ?, ";
    $bindParams[] = $phone;
}

if(count($bindParams) == 0)
    die("Nothing to update");

$query = substr($query, 0, -2); //remove the ", " at the end
$query = " WHERE uid=? ";
$bindParams[] = $uid;

if(!empty($condition)){
    $query .= "AND condition = ?";
    $bindParams[] = $condition;
}
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);

//if you want to bind parameters one by one:
$i = 0;
foreach($bindParams as $param){
    $stmt->bindValue($i, $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $i++;
}

//or:
$stmt->execute($bindParams);
```

You can extend the array and add parameter names, and types like `PARAM_INT`.
Also you should check and add `WHERE` only once if necessary, like when you don't use it by default in your query, but optionally if user provides

Comment: the only problem, they are using mysqli, not PDO

Comment: ah. I didn't notice it. but I think they'll get the idea, it can be converted to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

With your existing SQL query that you generated, you could simply do this:

```
$bindParams = []; // array to hold existing parameter values for binding
foreach(['prov', 'city', 'addr', 'code', 'phone', 'phone_alt'] as $param) { // Check all possible parameters
    if (!empty($$param)) { // If the parameter is not empty
        $bindParams[] = $$param; // Add it to the array
    }
}
$bindParams[] = $uid; // Add $uid to the array cause we always need it as the final value
$stmt = prepared_Query($con, $sql, $bindParams);
// Do whatever with $stmt
```